# Limit memory usage Unix

Tags: linux, matlab, unix, out-of-memory

I have access to a shared workstation running Linux and have to load in a large .csv file. However, I am uncertain how much memory that requires of the system as there will be some overhead and I am not allowed to use more than a specific amount of the memory.

So can I by any means limit the memory usage either inside Matlab or as I start the job itself? Everything need to happen through the terminal.

Comment: Maybe you can limit your program from eating up memory?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. However we don't edit titles to do that here - please make an answer below, and self-accept it, by clicking the adjacent tick mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I you are using MATLAB R2015 or later you can setup the array size limits in the Preferences:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html

In my opinion it would be a better solution to control the array sizes by your script/function.

Comment: I am sorry, that it was not stated in the original problem, but I have access through ssh, so I have to do it through the terminal. The problematic part is loading the file, which I have no control over per se..

Comment: So you're not working with the MATLAB-IDE? Are you calling a compiled MATLAB-Script?

Comment: No I run standard matlab just without the gui.